# Ext.toast position configuration

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, senchatouch-2.4

**Sencha Touch 2.4** has this **new toast class(Ext.Toast)**, which looks nice. But, by default, the location of the toast is centered in the viewport. Is there any way I can push it towards the bottom?

I looked at the **top config**, but it doesn't work well. (Pushes it down, but it's not centered horizontally now).

Tried a combination of **top and left configs**, but it's not perfect. I don't seem to find any hints in the docs.

Basically, I need to display the toast around of 70% of the height, and it should be centered horizontally in the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but the following css will do it. Just change the number depending on high high you want it.

```html
.x-toast {
    top: -150px; 
}
```

Comment: I wanted to push down the toast, so gave it a positive value, and it works. But, tried with percentages, but couldn't get it to work. Can I give it a relative position as per the height of the screen? Say, on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

I've [created a plugin](https://github.com/barrybear/SenchaTouchToast) that can create toast messages similar to Android style at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please make sure to note whenever you're promoting something you yourself are involved in.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this problem I found the solution.You can also find it by the below link.

[sample toast with different position and animation](http://www.eirik.net/Ext/ux/window/Demo.html)

Comment: You should edit relevant information for the solution into your post.